# How include another field on the Group BY

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I want to create a data set to display a tree view with all the fleet one user has and all the cars of each fleet

So the tree should looks like this

```
|
| - fleetName  -- fleet_id as node key
|  |
|  |--- plate_number  -- gps_device_id as node key
| - plate_number   -- for cars wont belong to any fleet
```

**customer_cars**

```
CREATE TABLE tracker.customer_cars
(
  customer_car_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('customer_cars_car_id_seq'::regclass),
  gps_device_id integer,
  plate_number  string
  user_id text NOT NULL,
  fleet_id integer,

  CONSTRAINT customer_cars_idx PRIMARY KEY (customer_car_id),
  CONSTRAINT cars_gps_device_fk FOREIGN KEY (gps_device_id)
      REFERENCES tracker.gps_devices (gps_device_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fleet_fk FOREIGN KEY (fleet_id)
      REFERENCES tracker.fleet_cars (fleet_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

**fleet_cars**

```
CREATE TABLE tracker.fleet_cars
(
  fleet_id serial NOT NULL,
  fleet_name text,
  user_id text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fleet_idx PRIMARY KEY (fleet_id)
)
```

What I try

```
    var customer_cars = db.customer_cars
              .Include(c => c.gps_devices)
              .Include(c => c.fleet_cars)
              .Where(c => c.user_id.CompareTo(UserId) == 0)  
              .GroupBy(c => c.fleet_id,
                       c => c.fleet_cars,
                       (key, g) => new
                       {
                           FleetID = key,                                   
                           Cars = g.ToList()
                       }
              );
```

But dont have `fleet_name`, only `fleet_id`  and the cars have the `customer_cars` rows without `gps_device_id`

```
foreach (var fleet in customer_cars)
{
    -- have id but no name
    string fleet_id = fleet.FleetID.HasValue ? fleet.FleetID.ToString() : "0"; 

    foreach (var car in fleet.Cars ){
        string fleet_name = car.fleet_name; -- have fleet_name
        string gps_id = car.gps_device_id ; -- dont have gps_device_id             
    }
}
```

Comment: Try : .GroupBy(c => new {c.fleet_id, c.fleet_cars}).  To get name you need to join the two tables by the id.

Comment: @jdweng in that case `fleet in customers_cars` is a collection not an fleet object. I should have `fleet = {fleet_id, fleet_name, list<cars>}`

Comment: I said you need to use a JOIN.  See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: @jdweng The problem was I remove the `SELECT` part when change to your `GROUP BY` now is working ok. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing a bit your group by key, you will get that you want:

```
var customer_cars = db.customer_cars
                      .Include(c => c.gps_devices)
                      .Include(c => c.fleet_cars)
                      .Where(c => c.user_id.CompareTo(UserId) == 0)  
                      .GroupBy(c => new { c.fleet_id, c.fleet_cars})
                      .Select(gr => new
                      {
                          FleetID = gr.Key.fleet_id,     
                          FleetName = gr.Key.fleet_cars.fleet_name,                                  
                          Cars = gr.ToList()
                      });
```

Comment: This is much better. Now just need the FleetName.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Hi, you edited my answer. You mean that is that you want and it worked or it didn't work?

Comment: Yes, I just test it and found myself. Now checking if get the right result.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Allrgiht

Comment: Can you elaborate why this work and why mine doesnt? Not sure how `GROUP BY` by a list make sense in `SQL`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Of course. Essentially, in your implementation the contents of the groups that were created based on the c.fleet_id, contained the corresponding fleet_cars, for each fleet_id. While in this version the grouping is based on both fleet_id and fleet_cars. For a thorough explanation of GroupBy, if you have the time, then reading this https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/01/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-21-groupby/ would pay dividends.